# Spark having different logs for each task in worker

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to have different logs file for task in a single worker?
Right now I get all the logs in the same file (for different tasks) in the worker.

I am using spark-standalone and the log directory is in SPARK_HOME/work

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `SPARK_WORKER_DIR` for each individual worker via the `spark-env.sh` configuration file. By changing this setting it will change where the logs are output by default.

See the [deployment documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#cluster-launch-scripts) for more information.